# Timer speeding up

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I wrote a simple WinForm program in C# that displays the time, updating every second by creating an event. Although it starts off fine, after some time I notice that it's updating more quickly than every second. As more time passes, it continues to increase its updating speed. Any thoughts?

```
public static void Update(){
    if(!Pause) {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source,ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        Form1obj.updateLabel1(DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

In my Form class:

```
public void updateLabel1(string msg) {

    if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(updateLabel1);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { msg });
    }
    else
        this.label1.Text = msg;

}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not subscribing to `OnTimedEvent` several times.

Comment: @zespri- looking at the code again, that looks like the most likely culprit.  You may want to add it as an answer.

Comment: There are several different conditions that result in a call to Update(), but I'm sure they do it only once per second in total. I'll try it with only one and see if this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call update multiple times you will be subscribing multiple times to the same event.

So make sure you only do the
`aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);`

once (when the page is constructed for example)

Comment: Once the first timer expires, I need to make another one right?

Comment: no. the timer is not disposed when it expires. have you read the doc?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm guessing AutoReset is set to true by default?